# Transfer music from phone to my OS X

Tags: sync, music

I've downloaded the [Windows Phone](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/windows-phone/id415571499?mt=12) app for Mac.

Every time I plug my phone in, though, only one song shows up in "Browse Device" even though I have roughly 20 songs on my 8X.

I've gone into my phone and I know that all of the music is ON the phone (it isn't on the cloud or otherwise wirelessly there).

How can I get the music to show up on my computer?

Comment: Have you given the Mac app proper access by going to File > Allow Access to Folder?

Comment: Just for understanding: how did you get your music on the phone in the first place? Are all the songs in the same folder?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone uses MTP (Media Transfer Protocol) for file transfer. I don't know what the state of MTP support in OS X is, but there must be some (even if it's third-party) so I'd start there. If *that* still only shows one file, you've got something really weird going on.

You can, of course, use other methods to transfer the files. Email them to yourself, send them to your Mac using Bluetooth, push them to OneDrive or similar and download them on the Mac, run one of the apps that acts as an FTP server on the phone and have the Mac connect to that over the WiFi, etc.